# How to import java file in Selenium IDE Chrome extension?

Tags: selenium, testing, selenium-ide

Is there a way I can import a java file with tests in Selenium IDE? I have the chrome extension and I need to do it for a project. I did not find answers anywhere, so any help is welcome. Thanks!

Comment: nope. Pretty sure the new IDE only handles exporting as java